# Why is the font-size of the anchor tag 18 pixels after css reset?

Tags: html, css

After a css reset the `font-size` of the anchor tag comes out to be 18px while the paragraph comes out to be 19px. How is this calculated and why are they different?

```css
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1.2;
}
ol { 
 padding-left: 1.4em;
 list-style: decimal;
}
ul {
 padding-left: 1.4em;
 list-style: square;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Anchor tag</a>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the anchor tag, being by default an inline element, is the height of the text characters. That's from the the top of the ascent of the font metrics to the bottom of the descent. Depending on the font involved, that may be greater than, same as or less than the font-size, but will be proportional to it.

The height of the paragraph, being by default a block container element containing only inline boxes, is the height of the sum of the line-heights of the stack of line boxes it contains. Since in your case it contains only one line box, its height is the line height of that line box. Since the line-height is by default proportional to the font-size, the paragraph's height is also proportional to the font-size, but its proportion is set by the user-agent stylesheet, not by the font metrics.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the `font-size`, that's the height of the box.

The font-size is 16px in both cases.

Comment: I was going to say, that does *not* look like 18px!

Comment: So how are these numbers in my screenshots produced?

Comment: Those are the dimensions of the box, after the browsers takes all factors into consideration (e.g. `height`, `width`, `line-height`, `font-size`, etc.).

Comment: Read about *specified*, *computed*, *used* and *actual* values: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#value-stages

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures are showing the element width and height, not the font size. The paragraph might be larger do to being a block element.